# Save output from Prolog execution

Tags: prolog

I am running a tool in Prolog, and after I execute it, the result will appear on the screen, inside the Prolog shell. How can I copy this result into another file?

Answer (score 0):

From the command line you can do this:

```
script <file Name>
run your prolog program
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

you never said what prolog interpreter you're using.
This code works for Edinburgh-compatible version of Prolog, 
SWI-Prolog (on Fedora) in my case.

if you have a file hello.pl:

```
 hello_world :- write('Hello World!').
```

then

```
consult('hello').
qsave_program(hello,[stand_alone(true),goal(hello_world)]).
```

quit interpreter and in the shell:

```
$chmod +x hello
./hello > output_file
```

it doesn't return to shell when it's done, so you need to find a way to check whether or not your program finished execution and then Ctrl-d and check your output_file 
hope this helps